# Running DOH on the command line with node.js

Tags: dojo, doh

My first attempt to run tests using Dojo 1.8.3 on the command line with
`node` was thwarted by this error message:

```
../dojo/dojo.js:15
ode:function(){return _25;},guardCheckComplete:_37};};if(1){var _38=location.p
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

The workaround is to use the uncompressed source instead of the release,
since the *optimized version only seems to work in a browser*. Next I tried a configuration script

```
// bootstrap.js
dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: ".",
    packages:[{name: 'dojo', location: '../dojo_src'}],
    deps: ['./ui_test.js']
};
require('../dojo_src/dojo.js');
```

And a simple test

```
// ui_test.js
dojo.require("doh.runner");
doh.register("test_1", [
    function four_eq_4() {
        var x = 4;
        doh.is(x.toString(), "4");
    }
]);
doh.run();
console.log("done.");
```

When I run the tests `doh.run()` does not seem to have an effect

```
$ node bootstrap.js
done.
```

My directory structure:

```
/app
    bootstrap.js
    ui_test.js
/util/doh
/dojo_src
```

What is the correct way to use DOH on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, but not obvious. Run with `load=doh` to invoke the test runner.

```
$ node bootstrap.js load=odh
```